# Vuetify menu component auto property doesn't center the menu items properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify menu (as a popover) and in the docs it says that the auto property centers the menu items but for some reason the menu item is not centered horizontally (in this case it is a card).

Am I missing something important here that I haven't noticed?

From the documentation

> *auto* - Centers list on selected element

```
<v-menu
  v-model="menu"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  auto
  offset-y>
```

Here is the full example on codpen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMJOaY?&editable=true&editors=101